# Qt: Strange behavior when calling setGeometry on a widget in QScrollArea

Tags: qt, qscrollarea, qt5.4

My environment is the following:

- Qt 5.4, build from source with `-platform win32-msvc2013 -opengl desktop -no-icu -skip webkit`
- Visual Studio 2013
- Windows 7 x64

Consider the following setup (A QScrollArea containing a centered widget with fixed size):

```
QScrollArea scrollArea;
scrollArea.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(false);
QWidget scrollAreaWidgetContents;
scrollArea.setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
```

Now, I want to resize that widget within my program like the following:

```
int w = 200, h = 200;
scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(0, 0, w, h);
```

**And here comes the strange behavior:**
If `w` and `h` are equal to the current width and height (i.e. nothing changes), the widget jumps to the upper left corner.
If `w` and `h` are different from the current width and height, the widgets stays at its centered position and changes its size correctly.

I have written a little demo application that demonstrates the issue. If you click the `pushButton_Stay` button, the widgets jumps to the upper left corner.

```
    #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    #include <QPushButton>
    #include <QVBoxLayout>
    #include <QScrollArea>

    QScrollArea *scrollArea;
    QWidget *scrollAreaWidgetContents;
    QPushButton *pushButton_Up;
    QPushButton *pushButton_Down;
    QPushButton *pushButton_Stay;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;

    int w = 200, h = 200;

    void sizeUp() {
        w += 10;
        h += 10;
        scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    void sizeDown() {
        w -= 10;
        h -= 10;
        scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    void sizeStay() {
        scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    int main(int argv, char **args)
    {
        QApplication app(argv, args);

        // Scroll area
        scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
        scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
        scrollArea->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        scrollAreaWidgetContents = new QWidget();
        scrollAreaWidgetContents->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, w, h));
        scrollAreaWidgetContents->setAutoFillBackground(true);
        QPalette Pal(scrollAreaWidgetContents->palette());
        Pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::black);
        scrollAreaWidgetContents->setPalette(Pal);
        scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents);

        // Buttons
        pushButton_Up = new QPushButton(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
        pushButton_Up->setGeometry(QRect(85, 50, 31, 23));
        pushButton_Up->setText("+");
        pushButton_Down = new QPushButton(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
        pushButton_Down->setGeometry(QRect(85, 110, 31, 23));
        pushButton_Down->setText("-");
        pushButton_Stay = new QPushButton(scrollAreaWidgetContents);
        pushButton_Stay->setGeometry(QRect(85, 80, 31, 23));
        pushButton_Stay->setText("0");
        QObject::connect(pushButton_Up, &QPushButton::clicked, sizeUp);
        QObject::connect(pushButton_Stay, &QPushButton::clicked, sizeStay);
        QObject::connect(pushButton_Down, &QPushButton::clicked, sizeDown);

        // Central layout
        layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(scrollArea);

        // Main window
        QWidget window;
        window.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400);
        window.setLayout(layout);
        window.show();

        return app.exec();
    }
```

Clicking the `pushButton_Up` button:

[image: First picture]

Clicking the `pushButton_Stay` button:

[image: Second picture]

**Questions:**

What's going wrong here?

Is it a bug? An if and yes, can anyone confirm it?

If it's not a bug, how can I make it that the widget always stays centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's going wrong here?
>
> Is it a bug? An if and yes, can anyone confirm it?

It seems the second call of `setGeometry` with the same arguments **use different origin**, and the coordinates (0, 0) make the widget move to top-left corner. You can use other coordinates such as `setGeometry(100, 50, w, h)` to see the difference.

Here is the [source code of `QWidget::setGeometry`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/529b30b96435491fc6994515862f44d24efc754f:src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L6190-6206):

```
if (testAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_Created)) {
    d->setGeometry_sys(r.x(), r.y(), r.width(), r.height(), true);
    d->setDirtyOpaqueRegion();
} else {
    data->crect.setTopLeft(r.topLeft()); 
    //          ^^^^^^^^^ Could be the reason why (0, 0) move to top-left
    data->crect.setSize(r.size().boundedTo(maximumSize()).expandedTo(minimumSize()));
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_PendingMoveEvent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_PendingResizeEvent);
}
```

Personally I think it's a bug, but more evidences need to be provided until we can confirm it.

---

> If it's not a bug, how can I make it that the widget always stays
>   centered?

Actually you don't have to call `setGeometry` if you just want to resize the widget. Use [**`resize`**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) instead:

```
void sizeStay() {
    scrollAreaWidgetContents->resize(w, h);
}
```

It solves the problem in your case.

Comment: You are right. The resize function is much more appropriate in this situation, as the position is automatically determined by the scrollarea anyway. Thanks.